# function arguments loading to registers on x64

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, operating-system, cpu-architecture

I have this little C code

```
void decode(int *xp,int *yp,int *zp)
{
      int a,b,c;
      a=*yp;
      b=*zp;
      c=*xp;
      *yp=c;
      *zp=a;
      *xp=b;
}
```

Then I compiled it to object file using gcc -c -O1 decode.c, and then dumped the object with objdump -M intel -d decode.o and the equivalent assembly code for this is

```
mov ecx,DWORD PTR [rsi]
mov eax,DWORD PTR [rdx]
mov r8d,DWORD PTR [rdi]
mov DWORD PTR [rsi],r8d
mov DWORD PTR [rdx],ecx
mov DWORD PTR [rdi],eax
ret
```

And I noticed that it doesnt use stack at all.But firstly values still need to be loaded to the registers. So my question is **how do the arguments get loaded into the registers? does the compiler automatically loads the arguments to the registers behind the scenes? or something else happens?** because there is no instructions that would load the arguments into the registers.

---

And a little off topic. When you increase optimization for compiling the relationship between original source code and machine code decreases,imposing dificulties to relate the machine code back to the source code. By default if you dont specify the optimization flag to the GCC it doesnt optimize the code. So I tried to compile without any optimizations to get expected results from the source, but what I got was 4-5 times bigger machine code that wasnt related to the source and understandable. But when I applied Level 1 optimization the code appeared understandable and related to the source. But why?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI

Comment: Do not ask two questions at once.

Comment: @EOF yes I know, the first 6 int or ptr arguments is passed to the registers. But I dont understand how? I mean the registers can't fill up with data from air, the passing must translate to some machine code, or I terribly something missing?

Comment: @simple16 Where do you think that the arguments come from when they are on the stack? Do you think the stack fills up with data from air? When arguments are passed by registers the values come from exactly the same place.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Ohhh, now I understand that the instructions for loading arguments to registers happens in the caller. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments are loaded to registers in the caller. Example:

```
int a;
int b;

int f(int, int);

int g(void) {
  return f(a, b);
}
```

Look at the code generated for `g`:

```
$ gcc -O1 -S t.c
$ cat t.s
…
movl    b(%rip), %esi
movl    a(%rip), %edi
call    f
```

Second question:

> So I tried to compile without any optimizations to get expected results from the source, but what I got was 4-5 times bigger machine code that wasnt related to the source and understandable.

This happens because unoptimized code is stupid. It is a straight translation of an intermediate representation in which each variable is stored in the stack even if it doesn't need to, each conversion is represented by an explicit operation even if one isn't needed, and so on. `-O1` is the best level of optimization for reading the generated assembly. It is also possible to disable the frame pointer, which keeps the overhead to the minimum for simple functions.

Comment: I wrote main to test the program{int a,b,c; decode(&a,&b,&c);} but when I view the main machine code from objdump all it does is some weird instruction retz ret and nothing else. do you what means?

Comment: @simple16 The most likely is that your function `decode` gets inlined inside `main`. In order to make you an example I had to remove the implementation of `f`, otherwise GCC kept inlining it. If this does not explain it, then please ask a new question.

Comment: It makes sense. I also noticed that there's no code to load the local variables to the registers. Compiler manages assignment of variables to registers?

Comment: @simple16 If there are few local variables, they can live in registers all the time and not have a reserved stack slot. Also the compiler can use the same stack slot for local variables that are not live at the same time. There was a time when the only thing that prevented the compiler from doing this was keeping people who had to execute the code in a debugger sane, but nowadays, in theory, the DWARF3 debugging info format allows to store exactly this sort of information. http://dwarfstd.org/Dwarf3Std.php